# Rails Fixtures that reference local path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, fixtures

I'm using fixtures and I'm running a test where I need to access a URL of a file from a certain person. I don't want to go over the internet to fetch this everytime so I have downloaded the file and put it in my test directory `"/test/sample/somefile.html"`.

How do I write the local path in my fixture file so I can access `file_path` within my test.

```
#BEFORE
three: 
 id: 3
 user: Joey
 file_path: http://www.google.com/somefile.html
 last_modified:



#AFTER
three: 
 id: 3
 user: Joey
 file_path: <%= "./test/sample/somefile.html" %>
 last_modified:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
three: 
  id: 3
  user: Joey
  file_path: <%= "#{Rails.root}/test/sample/somefile.html" %>
  last_modified:
```

Or use `RAILS_ROOT` if you have an old version of Rails.

Comment: I am getting access to the file but can I make it seem like a URL instead of a file path in my tests?

Comment: I can't see how. Alternate solution: put the file in your public folder, then you'll be able to use its url.